# How to define .inx parameter's max value in Inkscape to depend on some other parameter

Tags: inkscape

I'm working on the parametrized generation of some figures on Inkscape, and the max value of a parameter depends of the chosen value of some other parameter.

I have searched a lot on the internet but found nothing about how to set this.

In my case, I want to set up a function f that gives me: ratio_max = f(columns):

```
<param name="columns" type="int" min="3" max="100" _gui-text="Cols">6</param>
<param name="ratio" type="float" min="0.5" max="1" precision="3" appearance="full" _gui-text="ratio">1.0</param>
```

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with current Inkscape 0.92.4, inx files are static.